My seleniumbase code stopped working even though I didn't change anything
I'm still a beginner in coding and I wrote a simple script to scrape some data from a real estate website and it worked just fine for a few weeks, but now it simply stopped working because it can't find the elements anymore.
I'm getting the "selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element" error even though the website has exactly the same structure, the selectors are still the same.
Here's the beginning of my code as an example:
from seleniumbase import Driver
from time import sleep

url = "https://www.wimoveis.com.br/venda/apartamentos/brasil?areaUnit=1&coveredArea=,72&loc=Z:42704,42705&page=1&price=300000,&sort=more_recent"
driver = Driver(uc=True)
driver.open(url)
sleep(4)
cookies = driver.find_element(
    '#root > div.CookiesPolicyBanner-module__cookiesContainer___H0Vq > div > div.CookiesPolicyBanner-module__buttonContainer__aOGwX > button')
cookies.click()

The script breaks while trying to find the cookies button, but the selector remains the same on the website. It is now also unable to move past the cloudflare screen on its own, I'm having to click captcha myself, which wasn't the case just 2 days ago.
Does anyone know what might be happening here?

Cloudflare detects you as a bot.

@MauriceMeyer I can move past the cloudflare check if I click on the captcha manually, but even then the script cannot find the elements when the page is fully loaded up

You CSS_SELECTOR have some temp values so they have most likely changed, add a larger sleep and investigate the DOM with devtools manually.

@MortenB I did that, set it to sleep for a minute, and recopied the selectors (which were still the same in the end).

@MauriceMeyer, if that was the case, do you know why that started happening after only several days? As I stated, the code ran fine for over a few weeks.

You should never be surprised when your web-scraping code stops working. After all, you have no influence over how the web-site operates.

your code worked fine on my end, also can you try this driver.find_element('xpath', "//button[contains(text(),'Aceito')]").click() it worked for my end

@SIGHUP true, the thing is that I can't seem to find the reason why it stopped working, as the selectors are still the same and the website has the same structure

@x1337Loser thanks, still getting the same error though =/

hey uninstall the selenium base, and remove uc_driver from .local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/seleniumbase/drivers/ then install this again python3 -m pip install seleniumbase --upgrade, can this work for you, let me know?

@x1337Loser yesss, this seems to have solved it for me! Thank you so much!

nice, issue may be with the chrome driver i think
